# Present perfect and Past tense in a specific place

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, is-it-a-rule

> Have you seen/Did you see my shoes **in here**

Do I have to say **Did you see** because it happened in a specific place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these are acceptable.

Reference to a specific ***place*** is irrelevant. I suspect you are thinking of the ‘rule’ in formal English governing ***time*** reference with the present perfect. This  is often expressed in some such terms as this, from [www.englishpage.com](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html):

> You CANNOT use the Present Perfect with **specific** time expressions such as: yesterday, one year ago, last week, when I was a child, when I lived in Japan, at that moment, that day, one day, etc. We CAN use the Present Perfect with **unspecific** expressions such as: ever, never, once, many times, several times, before, so far, already, yet, etc. [*emphasis mine*]

This is imprecise. The ‘rule’ actually observed in formal practice is that you cannot locate the present perfect within a timespan *which does not include the present*. This is only indirectly a matter of specificity: locating an event at a specific point or timespan in the past such as *yesterday* or *when I was a child* excludes the present. But equally ‘specific’ time references which include the present, such as *today* or *this year* are perfectly acceptable:

> <sup>ok</sup>I have answered three questions today.

This rule arises because the present perfect, although it mentions a past eventuality, expresses a current state or situation which in some sense derives from that past eventuality: its ‘tense’, the time it is talking about, is present.

Answer (score 0):

Saying "Have you seen my shoes in the closet?" has the same meaning as "Did you see my shoes in the closet?"  The reference to a specific place is irrelevant.

However, saying **Did you see** is a more directed personal (accusatory) form of questioning than the alternative **Have you seen**.

Comment: You are right that in common speech these are often interchangeable, but one might, if one were being a smartass, answer the first one with,"Yes, I have, they are often in the closet.  They're not there now of course, but I *have* seen them in there."

Comment: @Jim You are correct and thereby reinforcing my point that **did you see** is a more pointed form of questioning demanding a truthful answer.