# Can "earlier this year" be used in the present perfect?

Tags: word-usage, past-tense, present-perfect, simple-past

Is "earlier this year" a specific time reference?
i.e. Can you say (A) is definitely wrong and (B) is right?

> (A) Earlier this year, ABC, Inc., has conducted a survey.
>   (B) Earlier this year, ABC, Inc., conducted a survey.

Comment: It depends on the context and the specific sentence. For instance, completely acceptable is something like: *"ABC has already conducted a survey earlier this year"*.

Comment: @F.E., thanks. Oh, "Earlier this year" can be used in present perfect depending on the context? I'm getting confused...

Comment: @F.E. that's a good example and acceptable in a context where we might imagine that more surveys will/might be carried out in the future. In your sentence we don't exclude the possibility that the company conducts other surveys in the same year. (Hope I've explained this well)

Comment: I see. I think I've got it. This is a test item, so it has to be revised so that there won't be any ambiguity. Thank you all!

Comment: It's a very quiet day today, so try coming back later. There are some users who are like hawks and can spot a double meaning a mile off. But in my opinion (A) as it is currently phrased, is definitely wrong.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Unfortunately, your explanation is not appropriate for that type of example (the example that I gave earlier). The 2002 *CGEL* explains this stuff on pages 142-6.

Comment: @F.E. What four pages to explain that? I don't have access to the book, but if my explanation is faulty, I believe you. (P.S the 4 pages is my way of joking)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you have been taught a ‘rule’ governing time reference with the present perfect something like this, from [www.englishpage.com](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html):

> You CANNOT use the Present Perfect with **specific** time expressions such as: yesterday, one year ago, last week, when I was a child, when I lived in Japan, at that moment, that day, one day, etc. We CAN use the Present Perfect with **unspecific** expressions such as: ever, never, once, many times, several times, before, so far, already, yet, etc. [*emphasis mine*]

This is imprecise. The ‘rule’ actually observed in formal practice is that you cannot locate the present perfect within a timespan *which does not include the present*. This is only indirectly a matter of specificity: locating an event at a specific point or timespan in the past such as *yesterday* or *when I was a child* excludes the present. But equally ‘specific’ time references which include the present, such as *today* or *this year* are perfectly acceptable:

> <sup>ok</sup>I have answered three questions today.

This rule arises because the present perfect, although it mentions a past eventuality, expresses a current state or situation which in some sense derives from that past eventuality: its ‘tense’, the time it is talking about, is present.

Consequently, *earlier this year* should not be used with a present perfect; but *this year* would be just fine:

> <sup>∗</sup> Earlier this year, ABC, Inc., has conducted a survey.
>   <sup>ok</sup>This year ABC, Inc., has conducted a survey.

ADDED:
F.E. points out that CGEL (5.3.3, 144-5) accepts an exclusive-past reference under “restrictive conditions”; for instance:

> ii. b. We’ve already discussed this yesterday.

CGEL remarks that “the *already* indicates that I’m concerned with the occurrence of the situation of our discussing it within a time-span up to now and cancels the normally excluding effect of yesterday evident in [iib].” That’s plausible, but I think it is grasping at straws; I, for one, would **not** find this acceptable in **formal** use unless it were marked, by a comma, as an afterthought, a supplement. In colloquial use, to be sure, this use is not unusual, and it may indeed become formally acceptable in another generation.

- **SUPERADDED** in response to F.E.’s request for “info related to today's standard English”
  <sub>Source: Hundt, Marianne and Smith, Nicholas “The present perfect in British and American English: Has there been any change, recently?”, *ICAME Journal*, 33, 45-63.</sub>

  > ***3.2 PPs with past tense adverbials***
  >   As pointed out in the introduction, the PP is increasingly used with adverbials
  >   that clearly refer to an event in the past. **Occasional instances are also found in
  >   our corpora of written English, but they are so rare that a more detailed frequency
  >   breakdown would be inappropriate** [*my emphasis - sb*] [...] Co-occurrences of the PP and adverbials that require the SP according to the usage guides are more commonly found in spoken English [...]
  >
  > ***4 Conclusion***
  >   [...]
  >   PPs with past tense adverbials are still rare and usually ‘locally’ triggered. As our conclusion on this point, we could use Kjellmer’s comment (2003: 18)
  >   on the use of perfect constructions without auxiliary have:
  >
  > > So some of what we are at first likely to regard as simple solecisms in
  > >     modern English may still be solecisms, but in that case solecisms with
  > >     both a respectable ancestry and some distinguished neighbours and relatives.
  > >     Whether they will reassert themselves as legitimate in the language,
  > >     unlikely as it seems, remains to be seen.

CGEL’s other example is quite different, and in fact bears out the rule:

> He has got up at five o’clock.

Here the time reference is not to an exclusively past occasion but to a recurrent situation in the course of a timeframe which includes the present. *At five o'clock* “is a crucial part of the potentially recurrent situation: the issue is that of his getting up at this early hour; there is no reference to any specific occasion, as there is in the simple preterite,” *He got up at five o’clock.*

---

<sub>NOTE: I've CW'd this answer because (apart from the additions) it is quoted almost verbatim from an earlier [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/204519/24489) to a similar (but not identical) question.</sub>

Comment: CW for newcomers is "community wiki" which means the user forfeits any rep points gained from this post.

Comment: -1. This answer post still doesn't have it right. There's bad info in it. For instance, the word **"yesterday"** can also be used in a present perfect. E.g. ***We've already discussed it yesterday*** (2002 *CGEL* page 144).

Comment: @F.E. the OP wants to be sure that (A) is wrong. It is. The question is not centred on how the present perfect is used, and its multitude of different uses.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What does your comment have to do with my comment under this answer post? This answer post has plenty of bad info in it, and that is what my comment said.

Comment: @F.E. if the CGEL has dedicated four pages on one aspect of the present perfect, I don't think anyone can summarise it in one short post. Sometimes you need to generalize.

Comment: @F.E. I have amended to acknowledge CGEL's observations; but I hold by the principle. :)

Comment: *That's plausible, but I think it is grasping at straws; I, for one, would not find this acceptable in formal use unless it were marked, by a comma, as an afterthought, a supplement. In colloquial use, to be sure, this use is not unusual, and it may indeed become formally acceptable in another generation.* <== That sounds purely like your own personal opinion, your idiolect. What would be better would be info related to today's standard English, especially since that answer post is supposed to be a "community wiki" answer post.

Comment: @F.E. Will this addition meet your need?

Comment: @F.E.: I believe that this is because *already* (in early 20th century British English, at least) triggers the present perfect, and in BrE, you ***cannot*** use simple past with *already*. This is not true in AmE, and as an American *"we've already discussed it yesterday"* sounds wrong; I would say *"we already discussed this yesterday"*.

Comment: @PeterShor Hundt and Smith corroborate (p.54) : S[imple] P[ast] with *already* in spontaneous conversations, 8% in BNC, 54% in LCSAE.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify the period during which an event occurred, you cannot also use the present perfect tense:

> *Earlier this year, ABC, Inc. has conducted a survey.
>   *Yesterday, ABC, Inc. has conducted a survey.
>   *Last week, ABC, Inc. has conducted a survey.

Instead, if you are simply stating that a discrete event X has occurred, you must use the simple past:

> Earlier this year, ABC, Inc. conducted a survey.
>   Yesterday, ABC, Inc. conducted a survey.
>   Last week, ABC, Inc. conducted a survey.

However, if you use certain adverbs that locate the event at a *relative* point in time, the restriction no longer applies:

> ABC, Inc. has just conducted a survey.
>   ABC, Inc. has already conducted a survey.

Comment: Thank you, @Erik. So "earlier this year" is a specific time reference, then.

Comment: @Teddy if the sentence had begun with "This year" then the present perfect could be used. The adverb, *earlier*, tells us "when", i.e. the first few months of the year (Jan-March presumably)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, thanks. "Earlier this year" is specific but "this year" is vague. Interesting!